# Simple Way to Experiment with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I first would like to probably apologize in advance for this question, because this is so low-level it's embarrassing.

Right now, I'm learning Javascript through Codecademy, and while I'm enjoying it, I want to have an environment where I can experiment with what I'm learning in a way where I can see results of what I'm programming, much like what I see when I'm going through the tutorials.

I'm sure I'm missing some incredibly obvious answer, but it looks to me like every system I've seen so far is for either writing the code or running it, not something that will let me quickly try something, hit 'run', and see what the results are. I've looked at Sublime Text, Aptana, and some other things, but they don't really do what I want.

I'd really just like a basic environment that's like Codecademy Labs, but in software form.

Again, I apologize, I feel really dumb asking this question, but I was hoping to get some help.

Comment: Try [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) :-) Also, almost all web browsers have some sort of console that you can open and type javascript into in the current page's context (e.g. ctrl+shift+j in Chrome).

Comment: http://codepen.io is another.

Comment: Your browser console too! And nodejs.org

Comment: Press F12. a fully functional js console will appear in most modern browsers (IE included)

Answer (score 1):

A modern web browser (e.g. Chrome) is a full-featured Javascript environment with a console, interactive debugging, and all manner of useful tools. Write your code in the editor of your choice (I do like Sublime, myself, but to each one's own) and open the file in your browser with the dev tools. You can even open the file in multiple tabs for multiple independent sessions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want offline solution only, then ya any modern browser like Google Chrome Console is enough. 
However you can also try the w3schools try it editor, you can run both html and javascript in it. I use it sometimes, quite simple and handy (although online)

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_basic